# Bad request em um servidor iis novo

Tags: c#, web-service, soap, iis-7

Tenho 3 servidores iis no de produção e homologação tudo funciona ok. Porém em um servidor novo que acabei de criar, instalar todas ferramentas necessárias pra rodar o asp.net e colocar o código fonte de um webservice em c# como um novo site, me retorna Bad Request através do SoapUI. utilizei o Fiddler pra capturar estas informações. 
Se utilizar o formulário de teste funciona.

Coloquei em modo Debug no servidor novo e ao efetuar chamada antes de entrar no método ocorre os erros

- A first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException'
  occurred in mscorlib.dll
- A first chance exception of type    'System.Xml.XmlException'
  occurred in System.Xml.dll
- A first chance exception of type
  'System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException' occurred in
  System.Web.Services.dll
- A first chance exception of type 
  'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tem alguma forma de saber o motivo da Bad Request?

Request:

```
POST http://localhost:8095/WebService/WebService.asmx HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: "http://www.host.com.br/GetMotoristaValidoPeloCPF"
Content-Length: 426
Host: localhost:8095
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ang="http://www.host.com.br/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ang:GetMotoristaValidoPeloCPF>
         <ang:usuario>user</ang:usuario>
         <ang:senha>senha</ang:senha>
         <ang:cpf>62710966972</ang:cpf>
      </ang:GetMotoristaValidoPeloCPF>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 04 Feb 2016 16:43:35 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Após muito pensar no erro System.UnauthorizedAccessException acontecer antes mesmo de entrar no método chamado, lembrei que os métodos possuem gravação de log dos xml de entrada e saída. Fui verificar a pasta nos quais estes logs estavam sendo gravados e vi que somente os usuários locais tinham permissão de escrita, porém o IIS utiliza o **IIS_USRS** para efetuar esta gravação, portanto nunca iria dar certo sem a permissão.

A solução para este erro é ir nas propriedades da pasta na aba Segurança e adicionar o IIS_USRS com permissão de gravação.

Answer (score 1):

A maneira mais prática de ter mais informações sobre erros no IIS é testá-lo localmente. Isso porque, por padrão, a configuração de erros detalhados não é exibida para requisições externas, até por questão de segurança.

Como se trata de um servidor novo, que provavelmente ainda não está publicado para acesso por usuários externos, você pode configurar a diretiva <[httpErrors](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webServer/httpErrors/)> através do atributo "errorMode" para o valor "Detailed". Dessa forma, qualquer requisição que você fizer e estourar uma Exception para o servidor, ele te retornará uma tela indicando mais especificamente o erro.

Essa configuração pode ser feita através da tela administrativa do IIS (para IIS 7, veja [aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/rakkimk/iis7-how-to-enable-the-detailed-error-messages-for-the-website-while-browsed-from-for-the-client-browsers)) ou através do Web.config da sua aplicação:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/> <!-- Se você configurar alguma página padrão de erro, não vai estourar a Exception para o servidor -->
        <compilation debug="true"/> <!-- Sem debug ele provavelmente não te mostrará diversas informações -->
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" /> <!-- a configuração em questão que expliquei -->
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Para entender melhor sobre essa configuração, recomendo a leitura [desse artigo oficial sobre o assunto](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/diagnosing-http-errors/how-to-use-http-detailed-errors-in-iis).

Comment: Deixei como solicitado, porém só me retorna o header. Via form de teste tudo funciona sem erros. Meu problema ocorre quando vou testar via cliente SoapUI, só me retorna erro 400, sem substatus e detalhes.

Comment: Até criei este novo servidor pois o local parou de funcionar, mas daí a surpresa que no novo também não funciona. Copiei o web.config do servidor pra máquina local, mas mesmo assim o erro persiste. Será que tenho que adicionar permissão em algum lugar?